# how to hide a headView of section on UITableView?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

i want to hide navigationbar and tabbar on touch and move on uitableview, blow code:
_headView from viewForHeaderInSection it's no problem.
but sometimes after block Executed, _headView is visible

```
if(_headView)
    _headView.hidden = YES; //
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    scrollView.frame = rect;
    _vc.navigationController.navigationBar.top -= navigationBarHeight;
    tabView.top =  SCREEN_HEIGHT;

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
}];
```

if i move hide code to completion block , it's run OK, but hide after 0.5 sec, it's slowly .

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    scrollView.frame = rect;
    _vc.navigationController.navigationBar.top -= navigationBarHeight;
    tabView.top =  SCREEN_HEIGHT;

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    if(_headView)
        _headView.hidden = YES;  //Delay after 0.5s.
}];
```

please help me , thanks.

Comment: I am sorry for my bad english

Comment: When at rest all of a sudden Quick sliding up

Comment: just set the header height to zero, for the headers you want to hide..

Comment: if(_headView){
            CGRect rect = _headView.frame;
            rect.size.height = 0;
            _headView.frame = rect;
        } 
like this set height is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

We have a delegate method for the setting height of section for `UITableView`

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

just return 0 for this, for hiding header.